# Django4 - Генерировать путь при загрузке файла

Tags: python, django, django-model

При загрузке файла надо создать папку пользователя (если ее нет), папку автомобиля(если ее нет) и загрузить туда фото.

/*username*/*ID_car*/photo.jpg

В документации этого найти не удалось =(
Как это реализовать в Django4?

Сейчас модель выглядит так:

**models.py**

```
class photo_car(models.Model):
    car_link = models.ForeignKey(Car, on_delete=models.CASCADE, verbose_name='Лот', related_name='images')
    car_photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos/%Y/%m/%d/', verbose_name='Фото')

    def __str__(self):
        #car_link = int(self.car_link)
        return self.car_link

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Фото автомобиля'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Фотографии машин'
        ordering = ['id']
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Всетакие нашел как это сделать.

[Вот тут](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/) документация где написано как это делать.

[Вот тут](https://fixmypc.ru/post/zagruzka-izobrazhenii-i-drugikh-failov-v-django-3-cherez-formy-i-modeli/#dinamicheskiy-upload-to) форум где объяснят как это сделать))

А если в двух словах то:

Документация предоставляет вот такой пример:

**models.py**

```
def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return "user_{0}/{1}".format(instance.user.id, filename)


class MyModel(models.Model):
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

Но в нем не очень понятно сказано что такое "instance" и откуда должен взяться атрибут user.id.

Дело в том что "user" это название одного из полей куда вы загружаете файл (то-есть MyModel).

Таким образом учитывая выше сказанное правильный и адекватный пример должен выглядеть так:

**models.py**

```
from django.contrib.auth.mobels import User

def user_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return "user_{0}/{1}".format(instance.user.id, filename)


class MyModel(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    upload = models.FileField(upload_to=user_directory_path)
```

Что изменилось?

Надо импортировать модель User и добавить в модель MyModel строку которая будет связано с User и после этого будет сгенерирован нужный путь сохранения